# Как решить проблему разрешения типа generic без раскрытия скрытого типа?

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, generics

Для минимизации описания проблемы, расскажу как можно кратче.

1. Публичный интерфейс : `interface IComObject : IDisposable, IAsSupport {...}`
2. Внутренний интерфейс: `interface IComObject<out TInterface> : IComObject {...}`

Мне нельзя открывать `IComObject<out TInterface>`, но, нужно предоставить пользователю доступ к методу который реализует объект, а точнее：

```
public TInterface IAsSupport.As<TInterface> where TInterface : IComObject
{
...
}
```

По сути дела, мне этого достаточно, но при реализации этого метода встал вопрос о том, как мне определить что за тип содержится в типе:

```
IComObject<???> : IComObject
```

Это можно как-то определить?

Все что мне приходит в голову, это еще один слой, с типом `object`, от которого я уже получу необходимую информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Можно между первым и вторым интерфейсом добавить еще один, доступный во внешнем мире, но ничего не содержащий, кроме самого дженерика, а скрытый наследовать от него. В этом случае у вас generic тип становиться доступным, а внутренний интерфейс вы не публикуете:

```
/// <summary>
/// Публичный интерфейс
/// </summary>
public interface IComObject : IDisposable, IAsSupport {...}

/// <summary>
/// Интерфейс без тела, доступный во вне
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TInterface"></typeparam>
public interface IVisibleComObject<out TInterface> : IComObject where TInterface : IComObject { }

/// <summary>
/// Интерфейс не доступный во вне
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TInterface"></typeparam>
private interface IComObject<out TInterface> : IVisibleComObject<TInterface>  {...}
```

Comment: Это не сработает если не поставить ограничение на `IComObject<>`.

Comment: Не понял, что не сработает?